# Hide VPN password in NetworkManager GUI (KDE) when storing password in a file

Tags: kde, networkmanager, vpn

To avoid entering any additional passwords for the VPN I store the password directly in the vpn.nmconnection file (root:root 600):

```
password-flags=0
[vpn-secrets]
password=strong_password
```

Switching from xfce to KDE, I happened to notice that the password is visible in the NetworkManager GUI. How to make the password not visible to regular user, only root
[image]

Comment: KDE ? NetworkManager GUI ? Do you explicitly mean the plasma-nm applet ?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the password from being displayed in the field it is enough to delete or comment `password-flags=0`